# Google maps - getting API key tow work with javascript styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My website template has some pretty cool styling on the Google map, which worked perfectly until google wanted me to get an API code. Got code and map works with basic styling https://spcadbn.org.za/Untitled-1.html

But cannot figure out how to add the code to my java script, which looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.803562, 30.993815); 
    function init() {

        var myMapOptions = {

            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatlng,


            styles: [{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "color": "#cdd9d9"
                }, {
                    "weight": 0.1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }, {
                    "lightness": 65
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }, {
                    "lightness": 51
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }, {
                    "lightness": 30
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.local",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }, {
                    "lightness": 40
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative.province",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "saturation": -100
                }, {
                    "lightness": -25
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [

                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "color": "#E6A329"
                }, {
                    "weight": 1
                }]
            }]
        };


        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, myMapOptions);
        var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div id="mapInfoBox">' +
            '<br><h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Find us</h2>' +
            '<h4><i class="fa fa-car text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Cnr Inanda Rd/Willowfield Cres, Springfield Park</b></h4>' +
            '<h4><i class="fa fa-envelope text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>info@spcadbn.org.za</b></h4>' +
            '<h4><i class="fa fa-phone text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>+27 0 31 579 6500</b></h4><br>' +
            '<h4>Opening hours:</h4>' +
            '<p>Mon-Fri: 8am–4pm Saturday: 8am-12.30pm <br>Closed Sundays and public holidays</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'img/map-marker.png',

        });
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });


    }
```

Comment: When I look at your page, you're already using your API key. Check this part of your HTML source: `<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&callback=initMap">`

Comment: The code you shared here is not at all the code that lives on the demo page you linked. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I was just showing that my API code does work. But not on my website, towards the bottom of the page https://spcadbn.org.za/

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your map working correctly and not displaying the error message you need to ensure that the google api script is included before any calls to your own `init` function - and more importantly the api uri does NOT need the `callback` parameter as is frequently seen when invoking a Google Map. The use of `async` and `defer` also are no longer required when using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);` to instantiate your map - I think it is personal preference which method you choose to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>SPCA - Durban & Coast</title>
        <style>
            #map{width:80%;height:80vh;margin:auto;float:none;}
        </style>
        <!--
            As you are using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);` the script url below
            does not require the `callback` argument with, usually, `initMap`

            The actual code below is unchanged from that above in the question...
        -->
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>'></script>
        <script>
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.803562, 30.993815); 
                function init() {

                    var myMapOptions = {

                        zoom: 14,
                        center: myLatlng,


                        styles: [{
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "color": "#cdd9d9"
                            }, {
                                "weight": 0.1
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "landscape",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }, {
                                "lightness": 65
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "poi",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }, {
                                "lightness": 51
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "road.highway",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "road.arterial",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }, {
                                "lightness": 30
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "road.local",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }, {
                                "lightness": 40
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "transit",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "administrative.province",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "labels",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "saturation": -100
                            }, {
                                "lightness": -25
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "geometry",
                            "stylers": [

                            ]
                        }, {
                            "featureType": "road.arterial",
                            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                            "stylers": [{
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }, {
                                "color": "#E6A329"
                            }, {
                                "weight": 1
                            }]
                        }]
                    };


                    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, myMapOptions);
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div id="mapInfoBox">' +
                        '<br><h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Find us</h2>' +
                        '<h4><i class="fa fa-car text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Cnr Inanda Rd/Willowfield Cres, Springfield Park</b></h4>' +
                        '<h4><i class="fa fa-envelope text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>info@spcadbn.org.za</b></h4>' +
                        '<h4><i class="fa fa-phone text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>+27 0 31 579 6500</b></h4><br>' +
                        '<h4>Opening hours:</h4>' +
                        '<p>Mon-Fri: 8am–4pm Saturday: 8am-12.30pm <br>Closed Sundays and public holidays</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'img/map-marker.png',

                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- lots of other page content -->
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This was tested using the actual key and loaded fine - good luck.

[image: Google Maps showing custom styles]

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I have done as you suggested and still have the same issue. I can also set up a plain html page as above and it works fine. (/Untitled-1.html) but if I copy and paste the exact same code onto my index page, it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use the init function on Window.Load event. The API will call the callback in the `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&callback=init">` whenever the API is ready.

Comment: The code on the demo page linked by OP uses `initMap` as a callback and the function in the shared code is named `init`... Also it might be worth giving a bit more details in your answer as to what that callback does and how it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but when I took out the init it doesn't load at all. Bottom of this page https://spcadbn.org.za/

Comment: Put it back and map loads with same error about API code

Comment: @SheilaMcCallum Your DOM has multiple problems, a lot of tags from your head breaks out into the Body tag. You get the error because you include the Google Maps API script in the HEAD and then at the end of the body again but now without a key just below ```<!-- Plugins --> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for picking that up. Problem solved!